# How can I use a function to display Google Maps in an HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

When my mouse goes over an image, I want to display google maps for where the image was taken. Where in `MapFunction` am I going wrong? Are the arguments in `div` being used incorrectly?

I am a beginner in HTML. I wanted to create a website where an image is displayed but when my mouse is over the image, the location of where that image was taken is displayed (i have the lat and long already in the code). To do this, I use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. I'm not sure where I went wrong in the functions. I understand that I can use a screenshot of the map for display purposes, but I need to know how to display google maps for future knowledge.

On a side note, why do I need to put in my API key if I wont be using my location? The instructions shown in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map say that I need to do this but I'm not sure why the API itself is necessary.

Thanks for your help.

```
<head>
 <style>
  #MapAndImg {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: lightblue;
   background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, white);
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <em> May 30 </em><br>
 <div onmouseover = "MapFunction()" onmouseout = "ImgFunction()" border = 5 id = "MapAndImg">
  <script>
   function MapFunction() {
    var loc = {lat: 51.12722222, lon: 114.20194444};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MapAndImg'), {zoom: 4, center: loc});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: loc, map: map});
    }
   function ImgFunction() {
    <img src = "https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/HomePage/FourPack/2018_05/Illustrations_499178960.jpg" alt = "editeted.jpg">
    document.getElementById('MapAndImg');
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(INSERT API KEY HERE)&callback=initMap"></script>
 </div>
</body>
```

The map itself isn't showing up when I open it on Firefox and Internet Explorer, even though a similar code found in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map does have the map show up.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: `function ImgFunction() { <img src =''....` that's not valid, you're printing html markup inside a script tag

Comment: _"On a side note, why do I need to put in my API key if I wont be using my location?"_ The google API is not used for your location. It is used as authentication, to show Google that you are a valid developer, and that Google should accept your map requests. Failure to setup an API will render the map functionality useless. It also allows Google to track and monitor your usage.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio oh I see. So I would need to create a variable rather than use <img>?

Comment: @Peki yes, or you can move the <img> inside the html portion of your code, and then you dynamically change the src attribute using javascript